# Visual Studio 2017 - My Drag is Broken

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Ok, sounds painful right?  Here's the deal:

I can no long drag anything into the solution window of VS2017.   I Have to put the files in the project folder physically then select ADD->EXISTING to get them into the solution.  This is very odd.   I Don't know when this stopped work (or actually if it ever did since I just install the 2017 version).  Can anyone enlighten me to a solution to fix this?  No, I was not debugging at the time.  I just doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio "as Administrator"? An elevated VS process won't do drag-n-drop with a non-elevated Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yup you got it.   Sad.  I seem to have to run it this way so I can use my local IIS instead of IIS Express.